# How to replace everything except a specific pattern with sed?

Tags: sed

I would like to replace everything but my ::ID and [ID2], but could not really find a way to do it with sed and keep to match, any suggestion?

For example:

```
TRINITY_DN75270_c3_g2::TRINITY_DN75270_c3_g2_i4::g.22702::m.22702 [sample]
```

I would like to have:

```
TRINITY_DN75270_c3_g2_i4[sample]
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For a given input as provided, this `sed` expression seems to do what you ask:

```
$ cat input
`>TRINITY_DN75270_c3_g2::TRINITY_DN75270_c3_g2_i4::g.22702::m.22702 [sample]`
$ sed 's/^.*::\([A-Z_0-9a-z]*\)::.*\[\(.*\)\].*/\1[\2]/' input
TRINITY_DN75270_c3_g2_i4[sample]
```

The magic is in using regular expression groups, and two backreferences to reconstruct the desired output.  To expound:

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
  .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
  ::                       '::'
  \(                       group and capture to \1:
    [A-Z_0-9a-z]*            any character of: 'A' to 'Z', '_', '0'
                             to '9', 'a' to 'z' (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
  \)                       end of \1
  ::                       '::'
  .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
  \[                       '['
  (                        group and capture to \2:
    .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
  )                        end of \2
  \]                       ']'
  .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
```

So `\1` is the first key you wanted to extract, and `\2` is whatever is in the square braces afterward.  Is is then reconstructed by `\1[\2]/`, creating your desired output.

Comment: could be great if you can explain it for beginners  :) . I understand how you keep the first part but not the second (i.e [sample])

Comment: I have added a detailed piece-by-piece guide to the expression used in the `sed` command.

Comment: `.` DOES match a `\n`. So you should fix the sentence: `.* any char except \n`

Comment: `.` _would_ match `\n` if it weren't already consumed in the process of splitting the input line by line.

Answer (score 3):

***awk*** alternative:

```
awk -F'::' '{ match($NF,/\[.+\]/); print $2 substr($NF,RSTART,RLENGTH) }' file
```

The output:

```
TRINITY_DN75270_c3_g2_i4[sample]
```

---

- `-F'::'` - considering `::` as field separator

Comment: or just `awk -F'::| ' '{print $2 $NF}'`

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -e '
   s/::/\n/; s//\n/
   s/.*\n\(.*\)\n.*\(\[[^]]*]\).*/\1\2/
' data
```

We mark out the ID by replacing the `::` occurring 1st & 2nd time. Then we take away anything but the marked region + [...] region

Results:

```
TRINITY_DN75270_c3_g2_i4[sample]
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you would like to keep the second field between the `::` separators + `[sample]`, so deleting everything before and after the field till the last <kbd>space</kbd> you could:

```
sed 's/^[^:]*::\([^:]*\)::.* /\1/'
```

This will match from the beginning of the line till the last following <kbd>space</kbd> (`.*` is "greedy"), and replace it *just* with the first "sub-expression" (marked with escaped brackets).

For more details on backreferences and sub-expressions see [this description on gnu.org](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Back_002dreferences-and-Subexpressions.html).

Comment: When using the extended-regex mode `sed -r`, the brackets don't need to be escaped.